# NextJS environment variable undefined in API route

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

I'm using NextJS v 10.0.9. I have created an `.env.development.local` file in the root of my project, [as described in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables). Contents:

```bash
API_SERVER=http://127.0.0.1:5000/map/abc123
```

In an API route:

*pages/api/objects.js*

```js
export function getObjects() {
    console.log(process.env.API_SERVER)
}
```

But when I run the application with `next dev`, this prints `undefined`. I have restarted my server numerous times since defining/changing the variable, but always get `undefined`. I've also tried adding a `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix, which shouldn't be necessary and isn't desired, but I wanted to see what would happen. Result: no change. I've also tried using `.env.local`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I found this [line in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) on API routes: "For an API route to work, you need to export a function as default (a.k.a request handler), which then receives the following parameters: req, res."

So I've modified the code in my API route to:

```js
export default function getObjects(req, res) {
    console.log("test ", process.env.API_SERVER)
}
```

But it still isn't working. I do not have a `next.config.js` file because, as I understand it, this is no longer necessary as of NextJS 9.4.

I have also tried declaring and using an entirely new variable in the file (`TEST=value`), but this is also undefined when I try to use it in the API route.

Comment: I think you have to rename the file to `.env.development`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried `.env.development`, `.env.development.local` and `.env.local`. All three get loaded when I run `next dev`, but none are populating the variable in the API route.

Comment: Do you have `next.config.js` file in your project?

Comment: No, because I'm on 10.0.9, so the docs say I only need to create the appropriate `.env` file and use `process.env.VAR_NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was how I was calling the API route. When I visited it directly in the browser, the environment variable was available and printed in the console just fine. But I had been following a tutorial that wasn't written for NextJS, and it had me import the API functions directly:

```js
// WRONG WRONG WRONG
import getObjects from './api/objects'

// [...]

export default function MyApp({}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        getObjects().then(data => {
            // do stuff
        }
    })
}
```